# grey lines around map cells in pdf export from qgis 2.18.5

Tags: qgis, export, pdf

I am working on a map from raster files in the map composer of QGIS 2.18.5 from a 5 min resolution raster - export resolution set at 600dpi:

[image: map composer].

I try to save the map as pdf, but for some reason, a gray line appears around -most- cells:

[image].

Any ideas? I have created a new project with just one raster but I get the same problem again.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the process you use to create the map and export the PDF?

Comment: Created a new QGIS project. Added a raster created in R. Loaded an existing style for the raster (gray lines present in pdf even if I use an existing QGIS style). Created a new print composer. Added a map. Saved the map. Exported as pdf using all preexisting selections under the Composition tab. When I open the pdf, I see the gray lines where map cells are in contact with the white of the map background, but not where they contact another colored map cell. Thanks.